# Get Specified Roles from IIS windows auth in Django

Tags: python, django, iis, wfastcgi

I have a django app hosted on IIS with Windows Authentication and wfastcgi. In .Net authorization rules, only a specified users/roles can access the app. I am setting up users by `django.contrib.auth.middleware.RemoteUserMiddleware` and `django.contrib.auth.backends.RemoteUserBackend` with a custom backend. I want to get user's "Specified Roles" and assign `Group` in Django. I was able to get the username by `request.META['REMOTE_USER']`, but how to get the "Specified Roles" of a user if they have any in Django?[Auth Rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FiebF.png) [Specified Roles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uf26y.png)[Web.comfig](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAWCU.png)

`backends.py`

```
class CustomRemoteUserBackend(RemoteUserBackend):

    def configure_user(self, request, user):
        username = self.clean_username(user.get_username())
        user.username = username  # Modify the user's username in the database

        # Extract the user's role from request.META or a custom header.
        user_role = request.META.get('HTTP_ROLES')  # Replace with the correct header name.

        # Define a mapping of roles to group names.
        role_group_mapping = {
            'Sales': 'Sales',
            'Admin': 'Admin',
            # Add more role-to-group mappings as needed.
        }

        # Check if the user's role is in the mapping and assign them to the corresponding group.
        if user_role in role_group_mapping:
            group_name = role_group_mapping[user_role]
        else:
            # If no role is specified, assign the user to the "unregistered" group.
            group_name = 'unregistered'

        group, _ = Group.objects.get_or_create(name=group_name)
        user.groups.add(group)

        user.save()
        return user
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62806295/how-to-get-the-authenticated-user-name-in-python-when-fronting-it-with-iis-http If you can get the actual user token, you can then try to get the roles. But note that it requires HttpPlatformHandler, not `wfastcgi`.

Comment: @LexLi I cannot get header `x-iis-windowsauthtoken` since my handler is wfastcgi.

Comment: But you have to move away from `wfastcgi` no matter what, and it is no longer maintained, https://halfblood.pro/running-flask-web-apps-on-iis-with-httpplatformhandler/

Comment: @LexLi Even `pywin32` cannot get me user roles. I can get usernames but not their roles.

Comment: Did you try `win32security.GetTokenInformation(token, win32security.TokenGroups)`?